# Rocket.chat Slack import works but messages not showing in channels

Tags: slack, rocket.chat

I have installed the snap version of Rocket.chat on my VPS. The install was successful.

Next I followed the Slack export/import instructions as per this guide:
https://docs.rocket.chat/use-rocket.chat/workspace-administration/import/import-from-slack

The import seemed to have worked, however there are no messages showing in the channels. When I queried mongo, the data is there.

I also tried the 'Server File' import as per the docs, but this seemed to hang.

Screen grabs below. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]